# Boot problems (UEFI)

Tags: uefi

I have two drives, one is a HDD, it has windows 7 and an EFI partition
the second is an SSD it has some EFI files and the BCD.

Whenever I plug the SSD in, the PC always boots from the SSD, in which case it fails.

If I select the 'boot from EFI' file  I can select the EFI file on the SSD which points to windows 7 on the HDD. Some of the EFI files have been moved elsewhere now.

If I select other options such as 'notebook hard drive' it boots from the CD drive if there is a CD in the drive.

If I turn on legacy mode booting from the HDD boots from PXE and then the network adapter.

If I remove the SSD the HDD is automatically found and it boots windows 7, no messing with 'select boot device' menus.

So how can I plug the SSD in but have it so it boots from the HDD.
In the BIOS there is no option for the HDD, there is 'OS boot manager' and 'SSD' but nothing else that resembles a hard disk.

Answer (score 0):

I sounds as though your SSD is being plugged into a port with a higher boot priority. If you can give us some screen shots of your current BIOS/UEFI Boot setup, we may be able to help more.

Is there information on the SSD that must be saved? Formatting the drive should also resolve your issue.

Comment: Here is a video clip of the BIOS and UEFI boot menu:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzvbKWhZEhu1OW1UaDVPRU10YTg/view?usp=sharing